# Setting 0 margin in header using LaTeX's fancyhdr

Tags: latex

I'm trying to define a custom layout for my report for which I'm using fancyhdr. On the pages which contains a chapter start I want my header to contain a colorbox spanning across the whole page (0 cm margins) although keeping my defaults margin in the text area. I can get the box to span across the "margin notes" area, but not the other side. Here's some of my code:

```
\fancypagestyle{plain}{ % pages containing chapter start
    \fancyhead{}
    \fancyhead[RO]{\colorbox{NavyBlue}{\textcolor{White}{\raisebox{0cm}[1cm][0.5cm]{\makebox[3cm][c]{\textbf{\CNoV\thechapter}}}}}
}
```

Any ideas on how to do it?

**UPDATE**

[alt text http://docs.google.com/File?id=dg4jt6qx_10nnpxfqdj_b](http://docs.google.com/File?id=dg4jt6qx_10nnpxfqdj_b)

As you can see I want my header to span across the whole page (on pages containing chapter start). The text should have the normal margins..

Comment: Hi there. The image in this question has broken, would you fix? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [Fancy chapter headings](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/fancy-chapter-headings/) example at the texample.net site.
It appears to be what your are looking for.

[alt text http://media.texample.net/tikz/examples/PNG/fancy-chapter-headings.png](http://media.texample.net/tikz/examples/PNG/fancy-chapter-headings.png)

Comment: Good example. How do I place the chapter name in the middle (vertical) of the lightblue bar?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure what you want, but perhaps this is it:

```
\fancypagestyle{plain}{ % pages containing chapter start
        \fancyhead{}
        \fancyhead[RO]{\hspace*{-5cm}
        \colorbox{NavyBlue}{\textcolor{White}{\raisebox{0cm}[1cm][0.5cm]{\makebox[25cm][c]{%
            \textbf{\CNoV\thechapter}}}}}}
}
```